# Make Flow understand can only be the desired type in an IF statement

Tags: javascript, flowtype, typechecking, flow-typed

My code looks like this:

```
function func2(func2Inp: string) { /* some stuff */}

function func(inp?: string) {
    if(inp){ 
        func2(inp) // here is where flowTyped doesn't understand
    }
}
```

This is what Flow says:

```
Cannot call `func2` with `inp` bound to 
`func2Inp` because  undefined [1] is incompatible with  string [2].
```

How can I make flow understand that I'm sure that inp is not undefined?

**EDIT:**

As people Are saying it works correctly in comments, The exact situation is a ternary condition like this(maybe if and ternary work different here):

```
const x = inp ? func2(inp) : somethingElse
```

These Are Flow versions I'm using currently:

```
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.2.1",
"flow-bin": "^0.81.0"
```

Comment: If I try this out online at https://flow.org/try/ I don't get any error. Your code seems to be correct.

Comment: Your example is correct according to Flow. You would only get this behaviour if you have some sort of indirect check, e.g., `shouldRun = inp` and then you do `if(shouldRun)` does actually cause the problem you describe.

Comment: func method has optional argument where as func2 has mandatory argument if the inp is not defined func2 fails try to change func2 also uses optional arguement func2(func2Inp?: string)

Comment: @PDKPavanKumar yes, however the `if` will check if the argument is provided and if isn't, it won't execute `func2`. Flow *does* recognise this and does not raise an error, as it knows `func2` will always have an input. At least that's the case in the code provided.

Comment: @LukasMöller I editted the question and added explanation and exact condition

Comment: `const x = inp ? func2(inp) : somethingElse` still doesn't throw the error you say. It's still treated as the same code branching structure as the `if` and analysed correctly. At least that's the case when I try it in the Flow online tool

Comment: @VLAZ yes indirect check works, but looks like I need to do extra stuff just for typeChecking, isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: @VLAZ yes the link in try works with no errors, I even downgraded the flow version to 0.93 which I'm using currently, but it still says `no error` I don't know why my code is showing type error.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what you should do. I have just seen this problem show up in many code analysis tools. [TypeScript seems to have the same problem](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20func2(func2Inp%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%2F*%20some%20stuff%20*%2F%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20func(inp%3A%20string%20%7C%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20shouldRun%20%3D%20inp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(shouldRun)%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20func2(inp)%20%2F%2Fproblem%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) - you have to enable strictNullChecks in Options.

Comment: @VLAZ maybe I need to add some screenshots.

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry My bad! I acted like an idiot! my code looks like this: `x && someOtherCondition ? func2(x, someThing) : func2(x, someThingElse)` and it is giving me the error on the second branch, i.e. else branch, where there is no checking if x is not defined!

Comment: Yeah, in that second branch it's unknown if `x` is `undefined` or if `someOtherCondition` is incorrect, so Flow cannot guarantee that `x` is present.